# Selectpicker : ng-options working with json but <option> not showing anything

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I'm trying to display different server's id in a custom selectpicker. The selectpicker works fine if the options tag are "hard coded" but not when I try to retrieve them from a json file (the json is good since the same works with a table in the same page).

Working:

```
<select id="bs3Select" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control" multiple data-live-search="true">
    <option>cow</option>
    <option>bull</option>
    <option class="get-class" disabled>ox</option>
</select>
```

Not working:

```
<select ...ng-model="selected" ng-options="project.idproject as project.idserver for project in projects">
    <option value="">-- YON --</option>
</select>
```

The weird thing is that for each hard-coded option in the second case (like "--YON--" here), when I click it, the server's id corresponding (meaning, if I have two options, the second server id in my json is corresponding to the second option) is displayed in the select!

I tried quite every syntax I have seen on the web but still not working...
Someone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a simple plnkr for you http://plnkr.co/edit/2SbSwL05nx5Ta8KevEDC?p=preview
that is working, can you maybe post a sample of that JSON is it object of objects or array of objects?

Comment: Here is the json:

'[
    {
        "idproject": 2, 
        "name": "project manhattan", 
        "idserver": "22", 
        "idusers": [
   11,
   14,
   8
  ]
    }, 
 {
        "idproject": 3, 
        "name": "project hollywood", 
        "idserver": "10", 
        "idusers": [
   11,
   6
  ]
    }, ...
]'